# how to install MPLAB X IDE v3.00 Beta in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I am using ubuntu 12.04 version and tried to install MPLAB X IDE v3.00 Beta. but I can not install it. the downloaded file as .tar format(if I open the .tar file it have .sh formate).
how do i install and what are all the procedure to install it?

NOTE: i am new to linux and there is no experience to install such a files

Regards
Ramanathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract .sh file, open terminal , navigate to where you extrated the .sh file and run that file with ./MPL... I forget what the full name of that .sh file is. Got it installed under Mint this same way

Comment: Currently it's 1:22 am where I'm at. So posted answer very fast. Let me know if you want me to include more details or write it all out by steps

Comment: request you to include step by steps to install the software

Comment: i tried with many ways as suggested some forums. but it never installed. request some one to help me to install this MPLAB IDE

Comment: tried with following comments. chmod +x MPLAB X IDE v3.00 Beta.sh and then, sh MPLAB X IDE v3.00 Beta.sh. but i got error as below, need to run as root user. how to I become root user?

Comment: add `sudo` before `sh`

Comment: finally MPLAB installed in lubuntu

Comment: @Ram congratulations ! ^_^ Happy coding, my friend !